# Neo4J Spring Data - Error adding element with @RelatedToVia relationship to index __rel_types__ using SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase

Tags: spring-data-neo4j

I'm working on Neo4j Spring Data project and have started using a "RelationshipEntity" and the "@RelatedToVia" relationship to better model some relationships.

The problem I'm having is if I run an embedded database everything is fine but when I run with a SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase I keep getting the error "*Error adding element... to index __rel_types__"*:

Any pointers would be great!!

**Stacktrace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error adding element 52 className AlsoKnownAs to index __rel_types__
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIImpl.addToIndex(RestAPIImpl.java:703)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPICypherImpl.addToIndex(RestAPICypherImpl.java:683)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.index.RestIndex.add(RestIndex.java:58)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.add(AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:139)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.addToTypesIndex(AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:131)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.typerepresentation.AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.writeTypeTo(AbstractIndexBasedTypeRepresentationStrategy.java:74)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.writeTypeTo(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:46)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.TRSTypeAliasAccessor.writeTypeTo(TRSTypeAliasAccessor.java:26)
at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.writeType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:199)
at org.springframework.data.convert.DefaultTypeMapper.writeType(DefaultTypeMapper.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:168)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.write(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:254)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:235)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:365)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.persistEntities(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:99)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory$RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessor.setValue(RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java:93)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.updateValue(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:112)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.update(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:100)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.ManagedFieldAccessorSet.add(ManagedFieldAccessorSet.java:126)
```

**RelationshipEntity**

```
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.EndNode;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelationshipEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.StartNode;

@RelationshipEntity(type = "AKA")
public class AlsoKnownAs {
@GraphId Long id;
String name;

@Fetch @StartNode private Person identity;
@Fetch @EndNode private Person pseudenom; 


public AlsoKnownAs setNickname(String nickName){
    this.name = nickName;

    return this;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Person getIdentity() {
    return identity;
}

public void setIdentity(Person identity) {
    this.identity = identity;
}

public Person getPseudenom() {
    return pseudenom;
}

public void setPseudenom(Person pseudenom) {
    this.pseudenom = pseudenom;
}

}
```

**Node Entity**

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.neo4j.graphdb.Direction;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.Fetch;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.GraphId;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.NodeEntity;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedTo;
import org.springframework.data.neo4j.annotation.RelatedToVia;

@NodeEntity
public class Person {

@GraphId Long id;
public String name;

public Person() {}
public Person(String name) { this.name = name; }

@RelatedTo(type="TEAMMATE", direction=Direction.BOTH)
public @Fetch Set<Person> teammates;

@RelatedToVia(type="AKA") 
Set<AlsoKnownAs> identities;


public void worksWith(Person person) {
    if (teammates == null) {
        teammates = new HashSet<Person>();
    }
    teammates.add(person);
}

public String toString() {
    String results = name + "'s teammates include\n";
    if (teammates != null) {
        for (Person person : teammates) {
            results += "\t- " + person.name + "\n";
        }
    }
    return results;
}


public void identify(Person person,  String nickName) { 
    AlsoKnownAs aka = new AlsoKnownAs();
    aka.setIdentity(this);
    aka.setPseudenom(person);
    aka.setName(nickName);

    this.identities.add(aka);

  }

}
```

**POM**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.teralitic</groupId>
<artifactId>geonames</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <spring-data-releasetrain.version>Fowler-RELEASE</spring-data-releasetrain.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <jvmArguments>
                    -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005
                </jvmArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>neo4j</id>
        <name>Neo4j</name>
        <url>http://m2.neo4j.org/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-releases</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

***Edited***
I can see the same issue was happening on an old Spring Data build: 
https://build.spring.io/browse/SPRINGDATA-NIGHTLY-JOB1-697/test/case/92176623;jsessionid=5EE45702C67548804FEF985C00F5DAD2

Still investigating what might have caused that.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem, works fine using GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( "neo4j.db" ) but fails when running on SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase ... Did you manage to solve your problem ?

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well in SDN 3.3.0 and have not been able to find a solution.  From the logs it seems it's possible that the relationship is not visible yet when the POST request is made to update rel_types.  That all said, SDN 4.0.0M1 has been out for a while and so far it has been working out well for me.  Check it out, I think the changes are significant enough where it may make sense to upgrade - http://neo4j.com/blog/announcing-spring-data-neo4j-4-0/

Answer (score 2):

Still can't figure a way to fix this issue cleanly.

My only workaround so far was to replace

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase
```

by the now deprecated

```
org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestGraphDatabase
```

I am now able to save @RelatedToVia relationships.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem here.

I use spring-data-neo4j 3.3.0.RELEASE and spring-data-neo4j-rest 3.3.0.RELEASE, i had also to add manually spring-data-commons 1.10 (https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH-635)

Using the deprecated class solved the issue, but i'm not sure on my configuration since Michael Hunger said (here http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-data-neo4j-330) to use the SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase....